# Most efficient database structure for multiple user types

Tags: c#, inheritance, database-design

We are developing a system using asp.net MVC and have encountered issues with our database design in terms of handling multiple user types.

We are currently using an inheritance structure to split the main core of users into their specific user types, where "Student" and "Lecturer" user types inherit from the parent "User" class. The only way to uniquely reference any of the user types in the code is through the UserID in the parent User class, which makes it confusing when referencing a lecturer and adding new user types.

An example of this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The UserID is a lecturer entry from the Users table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "UserID">This is the ID of the lecturer.</param>

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A UserID is Required")]
    **public int  UserID { get; set; }**

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A LevelID is Required")]
    public int LevelID { get; set; }

    public virtual Pathway Pathway { get; set; }

    **public virtual Lecturer Lecturer { get; set; }**

    public virtual Level Level { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModuleClass> ModuleClass { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignment { get; set; }
```

As you can see the "UserID" is a foreign key which references the "lecturer" navigation property, and ideally we would like this to have a unique name such as "LecturerID". Are there any possible resolutions to this which would allow us to continue using the inheritance structure?

Comment: Maybe consider _composition_.  Particularly when a _lecturer_ could well be a _student_ of another course at the same time.

Comment: Read these series of tutorials to get a better idea : http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: Think about column oriented DBMS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS. This allows for inheritance easily.

Comment: Since a person could be a student, THEN a lecturer later (I was a student and a lecturer at the same school in fact), this suggests that inheritance is not the right approach. They are roles played by a person. Use composition. Person hasMany roles.